# Atiyah classes of holomorphic vector bundles with trivial Chern classes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be compact Kahler and $E \to X$ a holomorphic vector bundle.  Then $E$ has an Atiyah class, $At(E)$, valued in the sheaf cohomology $H^1(\Omega_X \otimes \operatorname{End} E)$.  Suppose the topological Chern classes of $E$ vanish rationally.  Evaluating $At(E)$ on an invariant polynomial gives a class in $\bigoplus_k H^k(\Omega_X^k)$, which must vanish in non-zero degrees since, by the Hodge decomposition, they correspond to polynomials in the Chern classes of $E$.

My question is:

> Is it the case that the full Atiyah class itself, $At(E)$, is necessarily zero in $H^1(\Omega_X \otimes \operatorname{End} E)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. A counter-example : the vector bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(p)\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-p)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ has zero Chern class, but does not admit a holomorphic connection if $p>0$ (by a theorem of Weil, a vector bundle on a curve admits a holomorphic connection iff its indecomposable summands have degree zero), hence its Atiyah class is nonzero. If you want a higher-dimensional example just pull back this one by a morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Do you happen to have a reference for the theorem of Weil?  Also, do you know offhand if $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(p)\oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-p)$ admits a flat connection?

Comment: The theorem of Weil is proved in the original paper by Atiyah "Complex analytic connections..." A vector bundle admits a flat connection on a Riemann surface iff it admits a holomorphic connection (which is necessarily flat).

Comment: @PavelSafronov Thanks.  Also I just realized since $\pi_1(\mathbb P^1) = 0$ the only flat rank 2 vector bundle is trivial.

Comment: @PavelSafronov Err, now I'm confused.  Topologically we have $\mathcal (O(-1)\otimes \mathcal O(-1))\oplus \mathbb C = \mathcal O(-1) \oplus \mathcal O(-1)$.  So topologically, $\mathcal O(1) \oplus \mathcal O(-1) =   \mathbb C^2$ is trivial and so admits a flat connection.

Comment: Indeed it is topologically trivial, but does not admit a *holomorphic* connection.

Comment: Right, I should have said the following. Holomorphic connections on a holomorphic vector bundle V are the same as flat connections on the underlying $C^\infty$ bundle whose $(0,1)$-part is the given holomorphic structure.

Comment: By the way, it was a bit stupid of me to quote Weil's theorem: the Atiyah class of a sum $E\oplus F$ is obviously the sum of the Atiyah classes of $E$ and $F$, via the embedding $\mathcal{E}nd(E)\times \mathcal{E}nd(F)\subset \mathcal{E}nd(E\oplus F)$.

Comment: @PavelSafronov, you mean (1,0) part? Anyway, can you give a reference for your statement?